# Why does classOf[...] says 'not found: type foo' in this case?

Tags: scala, abstract-class

In my example I want to be able to return the classOf[frame] instead I get an error not found: type frame.

```
trait User extends VertexFrame {
  ...
}

object User extends Base[User] {
  ...
}

abstract class Base[T <: VertexFrame] { frame: T =>
  def test = {
    classOf[frame]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

classOf is used solely for class literals, like String, Int and so on:

```
scala> classOf[String]
res0: java.lang.Class[String] = class java.lang.String
```

To get a particular class instance you have to call .getClass method:

```
scala> val frame = "foo"
frame: String = foo

scala> frame.getClass
res1: Class[_ <: String] = class java.lang.String
```